# change d3.js geographic map size

Tags: d3.js

I just want make [this map](http://bl.ocks.org/3012590) a little bigger!

I tried changing SVG size, also G element size...

Geographic translate and scale functions just move the map up and down.

Any ideas?

thanks a lot

Pere

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the scale factor of the projection (11000 in your example). See the [documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Projections).

Answer (score 0):

Another option to consider is using the "preserveAspectRatio" and "viewBox" properties in the svg tag (If your map uses one):

svg id="mapsvg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 500 200"

By raising or lowering the viewbox numbers you can shrink or enlarge the map.